# Want to use iTween for 2d floor collision in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, collision-detection, unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple 2d side scrolling game using Unity 3D. When I say 2d I mean it will appear 2d, all background assets will be 2d but the main character will be 3d. What I want is an uneven floor surface. There will be no actual floor only what appears on the background, so technically i want to fake the floor collision.

I've looked into [iTween](http://itween.pixelplacement.com/index.php)  and this looks like it could do what I want. My idea was to use iTween to create a line matching that of the floor on the background. I would then match the main characters x position with the lines x position and then get the lines y position at this point to set the characters y position.

My only problem is that I can't seem to get coordinates of the line. There is a method in iTween called PointOnPath() but in order to get the coordinates i need to know how far along the line my character is by a percentage. This is something I do not know as my character is not actually following the line.

If anyone has any ideas on how I could accomplish this, with or without using iTween, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 0):

You could use Unity3D's collision. **BoxColliders** can be used to simulate flat ground surfaces and possibly the uneven floor surfaces you described by placing differently sized BoxColliders next to each other.

If you wanted to simulate *curved* collision surfaces, consider using a **MeshCollider** and import a basic 3D mesh (from Blender, 3DSMax, Maya etc.) with a low poly count that fits the shape of your level.

A very quick way to demonstrate this is to drag a couple of Cubes (GameObject->Create Other->Cube), select it, and right click->Remove Component on both the MeshFilter and MeshRenderer, leaving you with the BoxCollider, which you can move/rotate/scale.

The only problem I can readily forsee this causing is having steps/stairs or small height differences. Unity's example character handles this by having the player's collision as a capsule shape, which pushes the capsule up when it hits the size of a stair at a certain height. Alternatives can be fixing the stair-collision handling in code or adding an angled/sloped collider to the gap between steps.